# Firebase Admin SDK Push notification cannot be measured

Tags: laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I wonder if I can measure my push notifications open and receive rate, sent by my backend. I use laravel right now and I use firebase admin SDK to send push notification from my backend server.

However, I cannot measure my push notification open and receive rate because it doesn't appeared in firebase console. Is there any way out like if google have API for us to grab the push notification data, or anything else ?

I'm also open for using another push notification service, as long they provide the analytics tools for the push notification campaign.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kevin currently only the console allows automatic tracking of notification opens and other metrics. You could log these events yourself with the Google Analytics for Firebase SDK. Thanks for the feedback, this would be a useful feature.